# prunsrv installed service cannot start

Tags: java, prunsrv

[image]I tried to install a java program using prunsrv. The environment is Windows 2008 R2 64 bit, the jar file was complied with Java 1.8 64 bit. The result service registry entry was also attached.

The Java class source is similar to this:

```
package prcrun;

public class TestMain {

    private static boolean stop = false;
    private static int i = 0;
    
    public static void start() {
        while (!stop) {
        System.out.println("Started: " + i++);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        
    }
    public static void stop() {
       stop = true; 
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        start();
    }

}
```

Prunsrv script:

```
set SERVICE_NAME=PcrunTest
set PR_INSTALL=C:\prcrun\amd64\prunsrv.exe
 
REM Service log configuration
set PR_LOGPREFIX=%SERVICE_NAME%
set PR_LOGPATH=c:\test
set PR_STDOUTPUT=c:\test\stdout.txt
set PR_STDERROR=c:\test\stderr.txt
set PR_LOGLEVEL=Error
 
REM Path to java installation
set PR_JVM=C:\java\bin\server\jvm.dll
set PR_CLASSPATH=pcruntest.jar
 
REM Startup configuration
set PR_STARTUP=auto
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=prcrun.TestMain
set PR_STARTMETHOD=start

REM Shutdown configuration
set PR_STOPMODE=jvm
set PR_STOPCLASS=prcrun.TestMain
set PR_STOPMETHOD=stop

C:\prcrun\amd64\prunsrv.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%
```

Got the following error when I tried to start the service:
Windows could not start the service on Win2008. Error:1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

Please advice what did I do wrong on this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's inside the `c:\test\stdout.txt` and `c:\test\stdout.txt`?  Is there anything in the system/prunsrv logs? imho it's the only way to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @andbi There were no entries in the log files. It also generated a  log file when I used TS option to test the service but this file was also empty.

Comment: You need to specify --JvmOptions parameter.

Comment: @grzegorz Thanks for the info! I will try to see if that will resolve my issue.